Empty xfs drive has 50+ gigs used
OS is Debian. I have a new 8 TB disk. Formatted, it's 7.3 TB. Filesystem is XFS. Block size is 4096.
I used it a bit, then recently removed all files from it, but df still shows 52 gigs as used.
find . | wc -l
0

What is causing this? AFAIK XFS doesn't reserve a percentage for root the way that ext does, and furthermore, this is a non-OS data storage drive, I don't want a percentage reserved for root anyway.
What's taking up this extra space? How do I free this space without formatting the drive again?

maybe related https://serverfault.com/a/984152/481846

For reference: If you create a clean 73 TB XFS file system with default settings, you'll get around 4.1 MB of file system:
img=largesparse.img
dd if=/dev/null "of=${img}" obs=1024 seek=$((73*2**30))
mkfs.xfs "${img}"
loopdev="$(udisksctl loop-setup -r -f "${img}" | sed 's/.* \([^ ]*\)\.$/\1/')"
udisksctl mount -b "${loopdev}"
df "${loopdev}"

yields
Filesystem       1K-blocks  Used   Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/loop0     78381065948  4120 78381061828   1% /run/media/…

So, what you did was create files and delete them afterwards, which very likely means that across all 73 allocation groups, inodes were allocated, with inode B+ trees pointing to the extents these inodes used.
While it might be a bit surprising that these weren't fully removed when you deleted all files, there's probably good reason for it (you don't need the space right now, and if you do, then that's because you create new files – which then directly fit into these already allocated tree structures): deallocating them now costs, and you'll very likely re-allocate exactly the same structures when you need to use the space, anyways.
The other thing might be that the ordering of deletion meant that you have fragmented free lists; while all allocation groups are essentially (aside from the inode b trees mentioned above) in control of contiguously free blocks, the structure storing which blocks are free might not currently be contiguous. You can check the entries in the free space trees using
xfs_db -r -c "freesp -d" /dev/{your 73 TB block device}
#       ^  ^-----------^
#       |        |
#  readonly      |
#                |
#  command "freesp"ace with the "dump each free block" option

(which will probably just show one to five lines for each of you 73 allocation groups, if free space is contiguous)
Note that there's little motivation for the file system to defragment the free space tree structures and where they are saved on your block device at this point: you'll definitely have enough large contiguous swaths, so that allocating any amount of file space is trivial.

7.3 != 73, not sure it matters but still.

@pipe ah, true, my mistake. You'd get 8 allocation groups instead of 73, the rest would stay the same
